# Guava function arguments

Tags: java, guava

Following obviously works, but I do not like to wrap items in Tuple,

```
    ImmutableMap<String, Function<Tuple2<Double>, Double>> op = new //
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Function<Tuple2<Double>, Double>>()
            .put("+", new Function<Tuple2<Double>, Double>() {
                @Override public Double apply(Tuple2<Double> data) {
                    return data.Val_1 + data.Val_2;
                }
            }).build();
    System.out.println(op.get("+").apply(new Tuple2<Double>(3d, 4d)));
```

I want to write something like:

```
    ImmutableMap<String, Function<Double[], Double>> op = new //
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Function<Double[], Double>>()
            .put("+", new Function<Double[], Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double apply(Double... data) {
                    return data[0] + data[1];
                }
            }).build();
    System.out.println(op.get("+").apply(3d, 4d));
```

Help would be most useful, ty.

**Edit:** Problem solved, started using:

```
public interface T2Function<T> {
    T apply(T Val_1, T Val_2);
}
```

Comment: You could do this by returning another `Function` from your `Function.apply`, and then applying that to the second argument. `Function.apply(a).apply(b)`. The "inner" function would use `a` directly, and receive `b` as a parameter. This could be extended for `n` parameters. That would mimic Haskell's treatment of functions, but I'm not sure what you would gain from it in Javaland.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using an interface of your own, something like this:

```
public interface Operation {
  double apply(double a, double b);
}
```

Guava's `Function` is a single argument function and not really appropriate for anything multi-argument.

Another thing I've experimented with is a `ReduceFunction<F, T>` that happens to be usable for such a thing. It's for use with the `reduce` or `fold` operation and looks something like:

```
public interface ReduceFunction<F, T> {
  T apply(T a, F b); // I can't decide on good names for the parameters =(
}
```

This lets you do things like

```
List<Double> doubles = ...
Double sum = reduce(doubles, MathOps.add(), 0.0);
```

where `MathOps.add()` is a `ReduceFunction<Double, Double>` that does the obvious thing.

Comment: @CollinD: What is reduce and fold ? I don't get it.

Comment: @Emil: They are functional programming constructs, aka higher-order functions. A `reduce` will generally reduce a list into a single value by combining elements through a supplied function. A `fold` is similar to a reduce operation, except that it can be seeded with an initial value. The function supplied to the `fold` will then combine the list elements and the seeded value.

Comment: @gpampara: Is such functional programming done using an api ?

Comment: @Emil: Within the Java world, yes. Guava adds some of the foundations for these, making it a very good library to lever. Remember that there are Functional Programming languages that support this out the box - Scala, Lisp, Haskell etc. The addition of closures to Java will make higher-order functions in Java simpler, but looks like we're gonna have to wait for JDK 8 for those.

Comment: If you don't have lambdas - i.e., you're stuck on Java 7 as I am for the current project :( - I would go for an expressively named interface, because that's more readable then `ReduceFunction`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're after an equivalent to c#'s [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx): Specialised in your case with the args and return value of the same type.

There's two other questions with good answers about this..

- [Java's equivalents of Func and Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184418/javas-equivalents-of-func-and-action)
- [Equivalent of C# anonymous methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340231/is-there-an-equivilent-of-c-anonymous-delegates-in-java)

As some other answers hint at, you may be stuck in the middle between two paradigms here (OO and functional), something with which language design is arguably catching up quicker than good practice is. If you want to continue down that murky water, you could try [functionaljava](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava/).

See [Mixing object-oriented and functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015606/mixing-object-oriented-and-functional-programming) for more interesting discussion.